# Define default value for SingleOrDefault Linq method

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I try to get a data record ID from Entity Framework:

```
var plantAreaID = await db.PlantAreas
  .Where(p => p.Plant.CompanyNo == companyNo && p.Plant.Abbreviation == companyAbbr)
  .Select(p => p.ID)
  .SingleOrDefaultAsync();
```

The problem is, that there is a `PlantArea` with the ID 0. SingleOrDefault returns 0, though, if it doesn't find any record. So how can I differenciate between ID 0 and the case, where no data was found?

My first idea was to provide a default value -1, but `SingleOrDefault` doesn't seem to support that in this constellation.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`null` is the normal way to indicate missing values.

```
var plantAreaID = await db.PlantAreas
   .Where(p => p.Plant.CompanyNo == companyNo && p.Plant.Abbreviation == companyAbbr)
   .Select(p => new int?(p.ID))
   .SingleOrDefaultAsync();
```

If you want to use `-1` to indicate a missing value, you can say

```
var plantAreaID = await db.PlantAreas
   .Where(p => p.Plant.CompanyNo == companyNo && p.Plant.Abbreviation == companyAbbr)
   .Select(p => new int?(p.ID))
   .SingleOrDefaultAsync() ?? -1;
```

Comment: Thank you for your idea. I stumbled upon the `DefaultIfEmpty(-1)` method, followed by a simple `SingleAsync()`. Which one would you prefer?

Comment: @AndréReichelt I prefer `DefaultIfEmpty` as it avoids the need to cast to nullable `int` in the `Select`.

Comment: `DefaultIfEmpty` is probably better if you want to use a custom default value.
If you just want `null` I think I prefer my way, but that's just the way my mind works I guess :)

Comment: @DavidG I've provided it as a separate answer.

Comment: It won't matter for performance, since this will always be 0 or 1 rows, anyway.

Comment: *"`null` is the normal way to indicate missing values."* That's the answer. The cost is single nullable cast, i.e. zero. `DefaultIfEmpty` and magic numbers in general are worse. Note that returning `NULL` is natural for SQL even for non nullable expressions - the cast is needed just to make C# compiler happy.

Comment: @IvanStoev You are right. I wonder, why the developers of EF made this weird design desision. `SingleOrDefault` should always return a nullable. Just returning `0` is pretty weird and even impractical in some cases.

Comment: .SingleOrDefault() is only translated by EF (linq to SQL), it's not a design decision made by EF team for this exact purpose. SingleOrDefault() from the IEnumerable interface should return the default T if there is no single element in the sequence (that's what the name implies)

Answer (score 3):

I found another solution, that doesn't require casting:

```
int plantAreaID = await db.PlantAreas
  .Where(p => p.Plant.CompanyNo == companyNo && p.Plant.Abbreviation == companyAbbr)
  .Select(p => p.ID)
  .DefaultIfEmpty(-1)
  .SingleAsync();
```

Comment: DefaultIfEmpty is applied in query side, so not better than cast for example, and as some others said "null" is a cleaner way to represent no data.

Comment: @AFract That's true. But a nullable also introduces some (unnecessary) extra overhead on the client side, doesn't it?